# Aligning a Star Rating to the center of the Div

Tags: html, css

```css
div.stars {
  display: inline-block;
}

input.star { display: none; }

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #444;
  transition: all .2s;
}

input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }

label.star:hover { transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); }

label.star:before {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<div class="stars">
  <form action="">
    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
  </form>
</div>
```

How do i align div`stars` to the center of the `div` without ruining the `hover` effect, I'm tried changing the `float` but it either go right or left, or swap the `hover` effect, I want to keep it at the center of the `div` dynamically without moving a bit right or left.

Comment: Center of which div? The `<div class="stars">` is only as wide as the stars inside it?

Comment: @G.Hunt If i set the `.stars` `width` to `100%` the entire child divs will move to the right, But yeah, If possible to move it to the left after setting the `width` to `100%`, Then it would be the `.stars`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try one of the following solutions:

**solution #1 (using flexbox):**

```css
div.stars {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
div.stars form {
  display:flex;
  align-self:center;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
}
input.star {
  display: none;
}
label.star {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #444;
  transition: all .2s;
}
input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}
input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}
input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #F62;
}
label.star:hover {
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); 
}
label.star:before {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="stars">
  <form action="">
    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
  </form>
</div>
```

**solution #2 (using `text-align`):**

```css
div.stars {
  text-align:center;
  direction:rtl;
}
div.stars form {
  display:inline-block;
}
input.star {
  display: none;
}
label.star {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #444;
  transition: all .2s;
}
input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}
input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}
input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #F62;
}
label.star:hover {
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); 
}
label.star:before {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="stars">
  <form action="">
    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
  </form>
</div>
```

**solution #3 (without `<form>` using flexbox):**

```css
div.stars {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
  justify-content:center;
}
input.star {
  display: none;
}
label.star {
  display:inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #444;
  transition: all .2s;
}
input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}
input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}
input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #F62;
}
label.star:hover {
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); 
}
label.star:before {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="stars">
  <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
  <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
  <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
  <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
  <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
  <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
  <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
  <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
  <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
  <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
</div>
```

> **Hint:** With these solutions you don't need the `float` property!

Comment: Is it possible if i removed the `<form>`?

Comment: I guess the `float` is required for the `hover effect` direction

Answer (score 3):

Add the following CSS:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

It's probably worth wrapping the stars in another div to avoid putting central text across the entire body.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wa2vd409/

Comment: I don't think putting the entire body to `text-align: center;` would be a great idea for the entire page.

Comment: Oh, After checking the JSFiddle i understand now, I thought you meant really putting the `body {}`, Sorry for misunderstanding, my English isn't that good.

Comment: Updated the fiddle to not apply this across the body: https://jsfiddle.net/wa2vd409/1/

Answer (score 3):

You could even do that using `transform - translate`, change main div `position` to `relative` thus you can make use of `left` property to align in middle of page then using transform align that to center of page.

```css
div.stars {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative; /*Add this*/
  left:50%; /*Add this*/
  transform:translate(-50%,0); /*Add this*/
}

input.star { display: none; }

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #444;
  transition: all .2s;
}

input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }

label.star:hover { transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); }

label.star:before {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<div class="stars">
  <form action="">
    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This works backwards (star 1 on the right star 5 on the left) if you are in a responsive environment and the screen is to small

Comment: That's because OP have used float:right on child element, therefore at small resolution the sequence breaks as stated by you. Using media query this can be addressed. Check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e2xL1zaf/

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about horizontal alignment then yeah

`text-align: center`

should do the job, but if you are talking about vertical alignment then

`vertical-align: middle`

should do the job. I told you both because you didn't specify which one is needed.